# Order of AddFont calls in tFDPF generates error

Tags: fpdf

I am using tFPDF library (extended fpdf to include unicode fonts).

I have run into a strange issue when adding multiple fonts.  The following code does not produce an error:

```
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSans.ttf',true);
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVuBold','','DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf',true);
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVuBoldOblique','','DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf',true);
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVuOblique','','DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf',true);
```

But as you can see, I accidentally added a font called "DejaVuBoldOblique" which is actually only oblique, with "DejaVuOblique" being both both and oblique.  So, when I rendered the PDF the text wasn't displaying as expected.  However, I get an error when I fix the code to:

```
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSans.ttf',true);
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVuBold','','DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf',true);
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVuOblique','','DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf',true);
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVuBoldOblique','','DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf',true);
```

FPDF error: Undefined font: dejavuoblique

Any ideas here, why the ordering would make a difference?

Comment: Did you also checked your setFont() calls? Maybe they are still referencing the old font name? (I guess the error message would be another, but this is just an idea)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've reviewed your question what i understood you're trying to add DejaVu and DejaVu Bold font.
Your Code:

```
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSans.ttf',true);
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVuBold','','DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf',true);
```

use below code instead of above:

```
// Add a Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
$tfpdf->AddFont('DejaVu', '', 'DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf', true);
$tfpdf->AddFont('DejaVu', 'B', 'DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf', true);
```

DejaVuSansCondensed fonts available in tFPDF latest version i.e. ( http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php )

After downloaded you've to made fews changes in the tfpdf.php file function "SetFont". paste below code in line number 619.

```
/* Modified by Vinod Patidar due to font key does not match in dejavu bold.*/
if ( $family == 'dejavu' && !empty($style) && ($style == 'B' || $style == 'b') ) {
    $fontkey = $family.' '.strtolower($style);
} else {
    $fontkey = $family.$style;  
}
/* Modified end here*/
```

If anything is unclear please let me know i'm glad to help you!

Comment: i tried this but still getting **FPDF error: Undefined font: dejavu B**

Answer (score 1):

Something could be improved with the naming systems (`fontkey` values) for fonts in tFPDF.

The first time you add a font, tfpdf is making a sort of cache (if the unifont directory is writable), if you call `AddFont('font_for_big_titles','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',True)` it wil create 3 files:

1. dejavusanscondensed.cw.dat
2. dejavusanscondensed.cw172.php
3. dejavusanscondensed.mtx.php

The next time you request the file, it will load data from the cache.
Inside `dejavusanscondensed.mtx.php` you will find (among other values):

```
$fontkey='font_for_big_titles';
```

This caching is nice for performance I guess, but this `$fontkey` value is not working well unfortunately when you decide to do use the same font with another alias in some other PDF generating php file later:

```
AddFont('sub_title_font','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',True)
SetFont('sub_title_font','',24);
```

This will give you the error:

> FPDF error: Undefined font: sub_title_font

Because it loaded the font under the fontkey `font_for_big_titles` the one that is cached.

So this is the reason why you get that error. Quick fix: delete the cache files.

The development of tFPDF does not seem to happen in some public repo (?) there are only unofficial repo's unfortunately. The fix that I am currently testing is the following:

Find the lines that say:

```
    if (file_exists($unifilename.'.mtx.php')) {
        include($unifilename.'.mtx.php');
    }
```

And add a newline right after that: `$fontkey = $family.$style;` this should overwrite the fontkey from the cache to the fontkey you just set.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Change line 614 in tfpdf.php to `if($family=='arial' || $family=='dejavu')`

To get the different font styles (bold, etc) working with DejaVu (the supplied font file), you need to add this as a core font. In the file tfpdf.php, if you add `print_r($this->CoreFonts);` and you will see the following core font families:

- [0] => courier
- [1] => helvetica
- [2] => times
- [3] => symbol
- [4] => zapfdingbats

You need to map DejaVu to a similar font (namely Helvetica). So in the tfpdf file, it maps Arial to Helvetica. You can do the same with DejaVu.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case the generated mtx.php file (in your font/unicode folder) contained a local path to the file.

changed:

```
$ttffile="/Volumes/path/to/font.ttf"
```

to:

```
$ttffile=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/path/to/font.ttf"
```

which fixed the issue.

Also, double check the value of **$fontkey** which will needs to match the alias name you give it in FPDF.